# PHP array can't be made or filled up?

Tags: php, arrays

I am writing a piece of code which should get some information stored in `$_POST` into another variable, namely `$data`, which is an array. But somehow, the information of `$_POST` can't get into `$data`, even though the function `Correct_input` is working correctly. If I try this code, I get the following output:

```
    print_r($_POST);
    echo Correct_input($_POST["voor"]);
    $data = array();
    $data[0] = Correct_input($_POST["voor"]);
    $data[1] = Correct_input($_POST["acht"]);
    $data[2] = Correct_input($_POST["tuss"]);
    $data[3] = Correct_input($_POST["func"]);
    $data[4] = Correct_input($_POST["emai"]);
    $data[5] = Correct_input($_POST["tele"]);
    $data[6] = Correct_input($_POST["stra"]);
    $data[7] = Correct_input($_POST["post"]);
    $data[8] = Correct_input($_POST["plaa"]);
    $data[9] = Correct_input($_POST["opme"]);
    $data[10] = Correct_input($_POST["nieu"]);
    print_r("<br/>" . $data);
```

OUTPUT:

```
 Array ( [voor] => David [acht] => Kortleven [tuss] => [func] => IT [email] => davidkortleven@solcon.nl [tele] => telefooonnn [stra] => hiero [post] => 4208SB [plaa] => Daarp [opme] => Geeem [nieu] => on ) David
Array
```

The last "array" seems to indicate that `$data` is totally empty right? So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: it would be easier to analyze if you show what you're doing in correct_input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `print_r($data)` at the end. Your `print_r("<br/>" . $data)` first concatenates `<br/>` and `$data`, which results in only Array being printed.